# data access object pattern with abstract factories, creation over generic types

Tags: java, android, dao, factory

I'm developing a database application for android devices.
First thing I need to do is creating the data access layer.
For this I want to use DAO-Pattern with abstract factories.

For all DAOs i have one Interface witch contains the declaration that all data object needs to implement. (in my case: IDataObject)
The specific DAOs are all represented by its own interface, extending the base interface of all DAOs.

base interface:

```
public interface IDataObject {

  public IDataId getId();

  public void write() throws MyDataWriteException;

  public void validate() throws MyDataValidException;
}
```

a extensions:

```
public interface IDataSample1 extends IDataObject {

  public void setNotice(String notice);
  public String getNotice();

  public void setDate(Date date);
  public Date getDate();

}
```

To create an data object I want use abstract to use abstract factories, something like:

```
public interface IDataFactory<Template extends IDataObject> {

  public List<Template> getAll();

  public Template get(IDataId id);

  public List<Template> getList(DataAccessArgument arg);

  public List<Template> getList(List<DataAccessArgument> argList);
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class DataSample1Fac implements IDataFactory<IDataSample1> {

  public DataSample1Fac () {
  }

  public List<IDataSample1> getAll() {
    return null;
  }

  public IDataSample1 get(IDataId id) {
    return null;
  }

  public List<IDataSample1> getList(DataAccessArgument arg) {
    return null;
  }

  public List<IDataSample1> getList(List<DataAccessArgument> argList) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

I don't get any error so far, but now I want to implement an factory builder:

```
public class DataFactoryBuilder {

  private DataFactoryBuilder() {
  }

  public static<T extends IDataObject> IDataFactory<T> getFactory(){    

    if (T instanceof IDataSample1)
      return new DataSample1Fac();
    return null;

  }

}
```

I get following errors(line 8):

```
T cannot be resolved to a variable
```

and (line 9)

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataSample1Fac to IDataFactory<T>
```

Don't know how to fix this, any suggestions?

Comment: I tried :
public static<T extends IDataObject> IDataFactory<T> getFactory(Class<T> type){    

    if (T == IDataSample1.class)
      return new DataSample1Fac();
    return null;

  }
but i get the same errors

Comment: T is just an information about type. It's not an object itself so You can't call methods on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor Your's DataFactoryBuilder to something like that:

```
class DataFactoryBuilder {

    private DataFactoryBuilder() {
    }

    public static IDataFactory<? extends IDataObject> getFactory(Class<? extends IDataObject> clazz){    

        if (IDataSample1.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new DataSample1Fac();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is very close to what I needed, thanks.
I get following error when I create teh fac:
    cannot convert from capture#1-of ? extends IDataObject to IDataSample1

Comment: How did you get this error? SOmething like this DataSample1Fac fac = DataFactoryBuilder.getFactory(IDataSample1.class);? You should use IDataFactory<?> fac = DataFactoryBuilder.getFactory(IDataSample1.class);

Comment: That is not the problem. When I call fac.get(), than I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got following solution:

```
public static <T extends IDataObject> IDataFactory<T> getFactory(Class<T> type) {
    if (IDataSample1.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
      DataSample1Facfac = new DataSample1Fac();
      return (IDataFactory<T>) fac;
    }
}
```

but i get an warning on: return (IDataFactory) fac;

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from DataSample1Fac to IDataFactory<T>
```

I think that is not a problem, I just have to supress it